# How to undo last pushed commit

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have an open Pull Request on Github and I pushed a new commit to the branch/PR.
Now I want to just ignore/undo the **last commit only**.

this is the `git log` output:

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Author: John Doe <John Doe@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 19 22:55:39 2022 -0700

    last commit

commit yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Author: John Doe <John Doe@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 26 14:38:21 2022 -0700

    some tweks

commit zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Author: John Doe <John Doe@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 26 11:51:19 2022 -0700

    bla bla
```

I already pushed the `last commit` to remote / open PR.

What is the best way to "cancel" ONLY the last commit and leave things exactly how it was before the `commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`?

Is there a better/cleaner way than:

execute locally `git reset HEAD^1` to undo the last commit then push it?

Comment: The answer is, as long as you are on your own branch that only you push things into, is to reset locally back to the previous commit, then do a force push. This will **not** be appropriate if you are on a shared branch that others will push to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git reset commitId to undo the last commit
Else you can use git reset --soft HEAD~1 to uncommit the changes
Or you can use git reset --hard HEAD~1 to completely delete the changes